# how to avoid writing main() too many times in C?

Tags: c, program-entry-point, repeat

Let say I have 5 small piece of codes in C. 
Every time I want to test each piece of code, I have to repeat this process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   // code piece go into here
   return 0;
}
```

Is there way that I don't have to do this 5 times? I'm using Code::Blocks, that means I have to create 5 different projects, which I believe not necessary because each piece of code is small.

Comment: I use a (shell) script that generates template files for any code I need to write.  But my C template does not include 'main()' because I can type 'int main(int argc, char **argv) { ...; return(0); }' fast enough that it doesn't worry me.  It's good to save effort, but the effort saved here is rather minimal.  My template includes boilerplate comments for the VCS I use, etc.  My test code is usually surrounded by #ifdef TEST and #endif, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a good editor with code templates. Most feature-full editors (Emacs, vi, Scite, Textmate, or even MSVC if that's your cup of tea) have some support for them. This way, writing this boring template every time will take only a fraction of the second.

Answer (score 2):

Is this really so hard?  Every program you run needs a main function, and the text you've pasted there isn't very long.  Also, people *expect* to see a main function in C/C++ programs.  If you template this out somehow, you're just going to make your code confusing.

If the issue is that you have to make a *project* for every test you want to build, then I would guess you are not using your IDE correctly.  Is there not a multi-target project type that lets you have multiple test programs without all the extra project files?  If there is not, then perhaps you should be using a different IDE.

Comment: Yes, multi-target project is something that i'm really looking for. Anybody knows how to do it in Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Would template files or copying and pasting be too difficult for some reason?

Comment: In C, is there template? Please show me an example if u can. Thanks much.

Comment: I believe the templates in question would be a feature of your editor... you could have a template for a header file, another for an entry point (including your main function), etc. 

When you creat a new file, your editor pre-populates it with the configured template.